# Converting dataset distribution from daily to weekly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, dataset

I have a dataset about daily meal recordings as follows:

```
     Date          Meals           
   04-02-2020        2   
   05-02-2020        3  
   06-02-2020        2 
   07-02-2020        3
   08-02-2020        3
   09-02-2020        2 
   10-02-2020        1
   11-02-2020        3
   12-02-2020        3   
   13-02-2020        1  
   14-02-2020        2 
   15-02-2020        1
   16-02-2020        2
   17-02-2020        2 
   18-02-2020        3
```

I would like to convert the distribution of the records from daily to weekly so that the result would look as follows:

```
     Date (starting date of the week)         Meals (average no. Meals in each week)            
             04-02-2020                                  2   
             11-02-2020                                  2
```

when I run the below code:

```
df2=df.set_index('date')   # note that Date was datetime datatype
Output = df2.resample('W',loffset=pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-6)).apply({'Snack'  : 'mean'})
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SpecificationError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1382-5715acb0763f> in <module>
   ---->   1 Output = df2.resample('W',loffset=pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-6)).apply({'Snack' : 'mean'})        

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py in aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    279 
    280         self._set_binner()
--> 281         result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
    282         if result is None:
    283             how = func

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    364                     obj.columns.intersection(keys)
    365                 ) != len(keys):
--> 366                     raise SpecificationError("nested renamer is not supported")
    367 
    368             from pandas.core.reshape.concat import concat

SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported
```

Can anyone help? :(

Thank You
Shosho

Comment: Why your expected output is 2 for the first week? the sum is 15, and there is 7 days or 8 records. Neither will result in an average of 2.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? loffset is deprecated in 1.1.0

Comment: Thank you for bringing this into my consideration, I will check. Do you think there is nothing wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2 = (df
.set_index('date')
.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')
.sum()
)
```